# Not explicitly specifying method to be overriden in derived class. Is this supposed to work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, standards

Better explained in code than with words:

```
//Classes.hpp
struct Base
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
   //Nothing here
};

//Classes.cpp
void Derived::foo()
{
   //Do something here
}
```

I saw this compile without errors, but it strikes me as odd that you don't have to explicitly state in class Derived that you are going to implement "foo".

Is this supposed to work according to the C++ standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what compiler you're using but this is not legal c++. My VC and gcc return the expected error when compiling this code.

Comment: I saw it at a colleagues computer just now. He's using MinGW (the gcc port for Windows) (IDE is Eclipse)

Comment: @heishe: Now the question is, which ancient version of GCC he uses. :)

Comment: Actually, the problem kinda solved itself. Once he tries to create an object of the class, a compilation error occurs. This is equally odd, however, as his class isn't a template, so that error should occur even when he doesn't use the class at all.

Comment: @heishe: Did he actually *compile* the source file containing the definition? That he gets problems when instantiating a `Derived` should be clear, since it's an abstract class (includes one or more pure-virtual functions).

Comment: Well, he pressed "ctrl + b" which is "build all" in Eclipse... so I think yes. Thanks, though.

Comment: Notice this is a .hpp file - that probably isn't compiled usless it is included in the .cpp file